# Implementing AOL AdTech/One Ad Server ads on Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: ads, facebook-instant-articles

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with running ads on Facebook Instant Articles using AOL AdTech (now known as AOL One Ad Server)? If so how would one go about integrating this?

Unfortunately, all the documentation on Facebook’s developer site at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/monetization/direct-sold refers to Google DFP and not AdTech, and there’s nothing about Facebook Instant Articles within the help pages in AdTech.